# why not show the listview data on clicking the detail button

Tags: android, android-sqlite

i m designing the simply submit and get detail form. data store in database and fetching the data in database and show in listview.

but all thing are work properly but when i m clicking the detial button he doesn't show the detail of database.

please help me...

DBAdapter.java

```
package com.example.anew.demo;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class DBAdapter {
//COLUMNS
static final String NAME = "name";
static final String E_Mail = "email";
static final String PHONE = "phone";

//DB PROPERTIES
static final String DBNAME = "employee_DB";
static final String TBNAME = "employee_TB";
static final int DBVERSION = '1';

static final String CREATE_TB = ("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee_TB(name VARCHAR, phone VARCHAR, email VARCHAR);");
final Context context;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
DBHelper helper;

public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    helper = new DBHelper(context);
}

//INNER HELPER DB CLASS
private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TB);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
    // OPEN THE DB
    public DBAdapter openDB() {
        try {
            sqLiteDatabase = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return this;
    }
//CLOSE THE DB
public void close()
{
    helper.close();
}

//INSERT INTO TABLE
public long add(String name,String email, String phone){
    try{
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(NAME,name);
        contentValues.put(E_Mail,email);
        contentValues.put(PHONE,phone);
        return sqLiteDatabase.insert(TBNAME,null,contentValues);
    }catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}

//GET ALL VALUES
public Cursor getAllNames(){
    String[] columns={NAME,E_Mail,PHONE};
    String query="select * from "+TBNAME;
    return sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
}
```

}

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.anew.demo;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lv;
EditText nametext,emailtext,phonetext;
Button submitbtn,detailbtn;
ArrayList<String> details = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    nametext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nametext);
    emailtext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailtext);
    phonetext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phonetext);
    submitbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submitbtn);
    detailbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.detailbtn);
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item);

    final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

    //EVEMTS
    submitbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //OPEN
            db.openDB();

            //INSERT
            long result=db.add(nametext.getText().toString(),emailtext.getText().toString(),phonetext.getText().toString());
            if(result>0){
                nametext.setText("");
                emailtext.setText("");
                phonetext.setText("");
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            db.close();;
        }
    });
    //Retrieve
    detailbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            details.clear();
            //OPEN
            db.openDB();

            //RETRIEVE
            Cursor cursor = db.getAllNames();
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String name = cursor.getString(0);
                details.add(name);
            }
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            db.close();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.anew.demo.MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Details"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:id="@+id/nameView"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/nametext"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="E-Mail"
            android:id="@+id/emailView"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/emailtext"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Phone"
            android:id="@+id/phoneView"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/phonetext"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayput1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:id="@+id/submitbtn"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:text="Details"
            android:id="@+id/detailbtn"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayput1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you add some more information, ie what you've tried, what's doing what, etc?

Comment: When you say that it "doesn't show" the detail, what do you mean? Do you get an empty dialog? Does the program crash? Do you get a specific error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method in DB class,

```
public Cursor getAllNames(){

    sqLiteDatabase = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    return sqLiteDatabase.query(TBNAME,new String[] {NAME,E_Mail,PHONE},null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

Comment: ohh yes...its working thank you so mch

Comment: ohh yes... srry for that actlly i am new user..so i don't know